# Create a file and insert text in android

Tags: android

I m trying to create a text file and insert text . 
I added permissions in Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

but when i try to open a file and insert test :

```
  int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user

    }
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfile.txt");
    try {

        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        stream.write("test".getBytes());
        stream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       // FragmentTools.alertbox(getActivity(), "erreur d'écriture");;
    }
```

i have these errors :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/1B0C-330F/monfichier.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are creating the file before getting the permission you should put a **return;** after

```
if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        return; // or prompt a message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are prompting the user in

```
if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user

    }
```

correct? Because you didn't paste that code... If you are not sure how to do that take a look at this sample from google:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PermissionRequest

It will help you greatly.

Another note: if you are running your app on API 23 or higher (which it looks like you are) you must request the permission at run-time. Again, consult the google sample, it shows how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to create text file and insert data into that file.

It is working and tested

```
public void generateTxtOnSD(Context context) {
    try {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File gpxfile = new File(root, "YOUR FILE NAME");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append("CONTENT TO INSERT");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Txt Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Before calling this function check permission is granted by user or not.

For that, Use **PermissionAcceptor** [library](https://github.com/hp-harsh/PermissionAcceptor-master)

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works with this code :

```
    private void save(String string) {
    Activity act = getActivity();
    try {
        FileOutputStream stream = act.openFileOutput("myfile.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        stream.write(string.getBytes());
        stream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        FragmentTools.alertbox(getActivity(), "file not found");
    } catch (IOException e) {

        FragmentTools.alertbox(getActivity(), "can't write ");
    }

}
```